# Identify a city by the mountains and water body (probably Rio de Janeiro)

Tags: identify-this, brazil, south-america, rio-de-janeiro

Does this image (a Windows 10 wallpaper probably):

[image]

truly depict Rio de Janeiro in Brazil and surroundings of [Sugarloaf Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugarloaf_Mountain)?

Google Image Search has identified this picture as:

> Monumento Natural dos Morros do Pão de Açúcar e da Urca
>
> National park in Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

But I don't know how accurate this search result is.

Can someone confirm or provide some more detailed information on what part of which city this image depicts or maybe from which location it was shot?

Comment: It's Botafogo Beach as seen from somewhere near Sugarloaf Mountain (which is behind the photographer). The statue of Christ the Redeemer is out of shot to the left.

Comment: [This is](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Sugarloaf+Mountain/@-22.9492586,-43.1545757,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1sAF1QipNvRbwEXubW0CxmMnh3QMbc1XZRs4h0l7kmSb4G!2e10!3e12!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipNvRbwEXubW0CxmMnh3QMbc1XZRs4h0l7kmSb4G%3Dw203-h135-k-no!7i5357!8i3571!4m5!3m4!1s0x9980409039f845:0x8075d7bcdfbcb48c!8m2!3d-22.9492586!4d-43.1545757) the mountain in which the photo was taken.

Comment: Botafogo; yes, indeed, this is Rio.

Comment: I have accepted the most comprehensive answer however none of the answers has clarified what Google search result of "Monumento Natural dos Morros do Pão de Açúcar e da Urca" has to do with this. Is this some kind of natural park in close proximity to depicted place or is it a completely false Google guess?

Comment: Pão de Açúcar translates from Portuguese to 'Sugar Loaf'. The entire title translates approximately to 'Natural monument of Sugar Loaf Moutain and Urca Hill', which is the park from where the photo was taken.

Comment: one can even see the Fogo de Chao restaurant, if you are of the meat-eating kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed Rio de Janeiro.

The beach in the photograph is [Praia de Botafogo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botafogo), seen from the park surrounding [Sugarloaf Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugarloaf_Mountain) which is behind the photographer. The statue of [Christ the Redeemer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_the_Redeemer_(statue)) is out of shot to the left. I've marked an approximate location and angle of view on this map:

[image]
<sup>[Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rio+de+Janeiro,+State+of+Rio+de+Janeiro,+Brazil/@-22.951078,-43.190343,15z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x9bde559108a05b:0x50dc426c672fd24e!8m2!3d-22.9068467!4d-43.1728965)</sup>

This photograph shows the same area from the opposite direction:
[image]
<sup>By Halley Pacheco de Oliveira - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=23366134</sup>

Answer (score 3):

@arthurs-pass posted a comment with the location. He is correct. The shot is taken from, it seems, the first of the two mountains that make up Sugerloaf.

Here's a photo I took from what seems to be almost exactly the same spot:

https://www.flickr.com/photos/mastababa/30228412800/

Answer (score 1):

@MastaBasta already answered correctly that this is Rio de Janeiro.

Specifically this shot is taken from the lower of the two mountains before you go on to the cable cars. Otherwise, you would not get a view of the side of some buildings on the right.

Straight ahead in the photo is Botafogo beach and the area around it carries the same name.